# How to use MySql MAX() in a WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have one table named `tbservicecallallocation` and below is data for that table.

[image]

From above data i want that of technician with their `MAX AllocationTime`.
Below image shows what result i want..
[image]

Please help me to write MySQL SELECT query for retrieve above data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a sub-query to return each technician's max AllocationTime. Join with that result:

```
select t1.*
from tbservicecallallocation t1
join (select TechnicianIDF, max(AllocationTime) as MAxAllocationTime
      from tbservicecallallocation
      group by TechnicianIDF) t2
  on  t1.TechnicianIDF = t2.TechnicianIDF
  and t1.AllocationTime = t2.MAxAllocationTime
```

Optionally add `ORDER BY` clause at the end:

```
ORDER BY AllocationStatus DESC
```

Comment: @lad2025, two rows, t2 won't contain any duplicates. I.e both rows will be returned if same technician twice with the same max(allocationTime). (Just like your query.)

Comment:  :) Yes, you are right. Second query will return always one row per technician.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbservicecallallocation t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 'NEXT'
    FROM tbservicecallallocation t2
    WHERE t1.TechnicianIDF = t2.TechnicianIDF
    AND t2.AllocationTime > t1.AllocationTime
)
```

Comment: I like NOT EXISTS. Some people say it slower than the join query when running MySQL, true or not?

Comment: For me is ever more fast than other statements. Because other solutions use JOIN and other statement where the complexity of sub query are greater than NOT EXISTS. So in this context all answers are right

Comment: Thanks for the info. (I've never used MySQK, I've only read what others have said about it.)

Comment: @JoeTaras I would not say it is faster. Keep in mind that it is correlated subquery. Where using `IN`/`JOIN` (maxAllocationTime) per technician is calculated once.

Answer (score 3):

You could use subquery to calculate max `AllocationTime`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbservicecallallocation t1
WHERE (TechnicianIDF,AllocationTime) IN
      (SELECT TechnicianIDF, MAX(AllocationTime) AS AllocationTime
       FROM tbservicecallallocation
       GROUP BY TechnicianIDF)
```

Comment: `@lad2025`. Sorry I can approve only one answer. Your answer is also perfect for me...but sorry for this time..By the way Great Work..

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
select t1.*
from tbservicecallallocation as t1 inner join
(
 select technicianidf, max(allocationtime) as allocationtime
       from tbservicecallallocation
       group by technicianidf
) as t2 on t1.technicianidf=t2.technicianidf and t1.allocationtime=t2.allocationtime
```

Comment: Same answer as mine, just 7 minutes later.

Comment: It might be a page refresh problem. I did not see yours when I opened the page :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM tbservicecallallocation t1
WHERE (TechnicianIDF,AllocationTime) IN
   (SELECT TechnicianIDF, MAX(AllocationTime) AS AllocationTime
    FROM tbservicecallallocation
    GROUP BY TechnicianIDF)
```

Comment: Same as lad2025's answer, just 27 minutes later.

Comment: oh okay.just now i seen  @jarlh